# attribute contains selector meta og not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a script to get the base url to use in meta tags and it doesn't seem to be working...

1st: My head looks like this...

```
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'> 
    <title>****</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="****" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="****" />
    <!--FACEBOOK OPEN GRAPH META TAGS - THIS IS WHAT GETS POSTED-->
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="*****"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<!-- TMPL_VAR street_no --> <!-- TMPL_VAR street --> <!-- TMPL_VAR city -->, <!-- TMPL_VAR state --> <!-- TMPL_VAR zip --> | $<!-- TMPL_VAR NAME=price -->" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Listing found at..." />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://sandbox.dev.activemls.com/property/photo/<!-- TMPL_VAR listing_id -->/1" />
    <!--END FACEBOOK OPEN GRAPH-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/shell.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=en" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/jquery-1.9.1.js "></script>
    <script src="/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/gmap3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/shell.js"></script>
    <script>alert(base)</script>
</head>
```

and my script is...

```
function baseURL () {
    base = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host+"/";
    return base; 
};

$("meta[property='og:url']").attr("content", base+"/property/detail/<!-- TMPL_VAR mls_number -->");
```

when i load the page, the og:url is still blank...

**CURRENT REVISIONS**

from shell.js:

```
/*******************************/
/*  GET BASE URL
/*******************************/
function baseURL () {
    base = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host+"/";
    $("meta[property='og:url']").attr('content', base+'/property/detail/<!-- TMPL_VAR mls_number -->')
    return base; 
};baseURL();
console.log(base);
```

html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'> 
    <title>A.A. Green Realty, Inc. - Wood Co. Real Estate Experts</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="AAGreen Realty, Inc. serves Northwestern home buyers and sellers in Wood County, Perrysburg, and the surrounding areas." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Wood County Ohio Real Estate, Wood County Ohio Properties, Wood County Ohio Homes, Wood County Ohio Houses, Wood County Ohio Housing, Wood County Ohio New Homes" />
    <!--FACEBOOK OPEN GRAPH META TAGS - THIS IS WHAT GETS POSTED-->
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Welles Bowen-Gio Realty, Inc."/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<!-- TMPL_VAR street_no --> <!-- TMPL_VAR street --> <!-- TMPL_VAR city -->, <!-- TMPL_VAR state --> <!-- TMPL_VAR zip --> | $<!-- TMPL_VAR NAME=price -->" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Listing found at A.A. Green Realty" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://sandbox.dev.activemls.com/property/photo/<!-- TMPL_VAR listing_id -->/1" />
    <!--END FACEBOOK OPEN GRAPH-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/shell.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=en" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/jquery-1.9.1.js "></script>
    <script src="/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/gmap3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/shell.js"></script>
</head>
```

url of demo site:
http://aagreen.dev.activemls.com

Comment: when is the code run? it should be run at least when the `head` is loaded. However I think the `<head>` part is useful only at the loading time (used by browsers or search engines ...)

Comment: the code is run in the <head> because this is for a template that runs across several instances with different base URLs, so i need the meta og to reflect that. so i load the scripts first in .../shell.js and then the meta tags in the head...hope that makes sense?

Comment: well if so at the time the script is loaded, there are actually no `meta[property='og:url']`, you should try placing the script loading after all the metas you want to target.

Comment: ok so the script is now loaded after the meta tags and still returning empty...i had to face palm myself about having the script loaded first...duhhh

Comment: not sure what exactly you mean by empty. I've just made a simple demo by setting `content` to `clgt?` (instead of the `base + ....`) and it in fact works http://jsbin.com/nobejusixive/1/ (try right clicking on the `Output` frame and select ***Inspect element*** or something like that), expand the node `#document > html > head` and you'll see it does work). I doubt that the script is actually not loaded successfully.

Comment: im getting this in console:

version: 37 Ex.js:1
ex.js page check url Ex.js:1
start addspshowad Ex.js:1
undefined Ex.js:1
addspshowad is closed. Ex.js:1
http://aagreen.dev.activemls.com/

Comment: from your ***current page*** (at the link you posted above), you placed this `$("meta[property='og:url']").attr('...` ***after*** the `return...` So it will never be executed. You have to place that code ***before*** `return...` (inside the function `baseURL`).

Comment: when i comment the code out in shell.js and just add <script>
    $("meta[property='og:url']").attr('content','clgt?')
  </script> directly to the page it still is not adding the attribute. can we take this to chat?

Comment: I don't think I could help you on this problem, so chatting is not really necessary. You could post the modified version of your page here, I'll try examining what's still wrong (by just looking in your code).

Comment: see my OP for changes

Comment: Not sure how you know it's empty, I've just tried your page and now it does update the `content` attribute correctly. See this ss http://i.imgur.com/hTB5Ftg.png

Comment: facepalm...i was looking in view source code, not inspect element